# PyQt: QLineEdit input mask for hexadecimal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

How can I use the input mask for QLineEdit of pyqt to limit 9 digits of hex numbers only. For example,
I want to limit user to enter hex from 0x300000000 to 0x400000000 only

Answer (score 2):

For this particular example you can use the `QValidator` class which provides validation of input text, please see example below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QRegExp
from PyQt4.QtGui import QRegExpValidator


def window():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QtGui.QWidget()

    flo = QtGui.QFormLayout()

    e1 = QtGui.QLineEdit("0x300000000")
    validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("0x[3-4][0-9A-Fa-f]{1,8}"))
    e1.setValidator(validator)
    flo.addRow("Hexadecimal", e1)

    win.setLayout(flo)
    win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
    win.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window()
```

Comment: That validator would consider `0x30` valid, the regex should probably be `"0x[3-4][0-9A-Fa-f]{8}"` instead. Even then it still allows intermediate states being entered, which could be corrected by overriding its `fixup()` method.